# what type of global ajax setting needed for checking response text?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to configure global ajax setting means this apply to all ajax request which will be  fired after this statement.

I want to check for all ajax responses text, is it possible?

if in response I ll get 'bye', I want to redirect to other url means to login page.

'bye' is sent through action.

below is sample code which is not work properly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $(this).on('ajaxComplete',byebye);

});

function byebye(e, xhr, settings){
        console.log('byebye()'+xhr.responseText);
        if(xhr.responseText=='bye')
        {
            window.location('login.jsp');
        }
}
```

this prints bye keyword on console but it does not call to `byebye()`;

Any solution for that?

execution of byebye() done but no execution of window.location();

Comment: This sounds like a scope issue. Where is your `byebye()` function declared?

Comment: byebye() is defined in js file.

Comment: Have you tried using the http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/ function instead?

Comment: Have you tried attaching the `.on()` to `$(window)` rather than document?

Answer (score 1):

window.location.replace() do nothing on some browsers.
You must assign value to window.location which is the correct way to redirect page, something like that:

```
window.location = newUrl;
```

Maybe you could try using ajaxComplete() global function callback to see whats going on.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).on('ajaxComplete',byebye);
});
```

Comment: And are you sure the byebye() is not called?

Comment: Use anonymous callback function, this is the print of ajaxComplete: .ajaxComplete( handler(event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions) )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18721/discussion-between-ankit5607san-and-roasted)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $(window).on('ajaxComplete',byebye);

});

function byebye(e, xhr, settings){
        console.log('byebye()'+xhr.responseText);
        if(xhr.responseText=='bye')
        {
            window.location('login.jsp');
        }
}
```

Assigning to the `window` object rather than the `document` object will probably fix your issue as I think globally AJAX events are triggered in the `window` scope.

Comment: the problem is window.location does not executes. that condition also becomes true.!